# detecting of click elsewhere then on button from custom color palette

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect case when color was not picked from existing options and user clicks anywhere on window instead.
You can test the code on:
https://jsfiddle.net/pr2501/5roh14ne/185/

At the end I have troubles with detecting of click on window.
As you may see in my example I did comment the part which does not work at my expectations.
I would like to detect if user does the click in the window and not on the color rectangle.

HTML 
 To peint the text

```
<div id="openColor" class="modalDialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="getTheTextID" value="Get the text at first"/></br></br>
                           <span id="textToColor" style="display:none">Then select the color for the text</span>
                             <div id="colorPalete1" style="display:none">
                                  <button id="B1" class="buttonA button1c" ></button>
                                  <button id="B2" class="buttonA button1" ></button>
                                  <button id="B3" class="buttonA button1a" ></button>
                                  <button id="B4" class="buttonA button1b" ></button>                                  
                               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;

}

.buttonA {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 16px;

  display: inline-block;

  margin: 8px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white; 

  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;

}
.button1a {
  background-color: white; 

  border: 2px solid #ff8000;
}

.button1a:hover {
  background-color: #ff8000;

}
.button1b {
  background-color: white; 

  border: 2px solid #ffa000;
}

.button1b:hover {
  background-color: #ffa000;

}
.button1c {
  background-color: white; 

  border: 2px solid #a00000;
}

.button1c:hover {
  background-color: #a00000;

}
```

The JS code

```
function showColorDialog(){
 document.getElementById("openColor").style.display= "block";
}
document.getElementById("openColorHref").onclick=showColorDialog;

var text1;
function getTheTextF(){
 text1 =prompt("Enter text:", "");
   if ( text1  === "") {
    document.getElementById("openColor").style.display= "none";    
   } else if ( text1 ) {   
   document.getElementById("textToColor").style.display= "block"; 
   document.getElementById("colorPalete1").style.display= "block"; 
   document.getElementById("getTheTextID").style.display= "none";  
   } else {document.getElementById("openColor").style.display= "none";}    
}
document.getElementById("getTheTextID").onclick=getTheTextF;


function rgbToHex(R,G,B) {return toHex(R)+toHex(G)+toHex(B)}
function toHex(n) {
  n = parseInt(n,10);
  if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
  n = Math.max(0,Math.min(n,255));return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n-n%16)/16) + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n%16);
}
var hex ;

function getColor1(){

    var border1=window.getComputedStyle(document.activeElement, null).border;
    var indexOfLAT = border1.lastIndexOf('rgb');
    var res1 = border1.substring(indexOfLAT+3);
   var R= border1.substring(
    border1.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, 
    border1.indexOf(",")
    );
     var G= border1.substring(
    border1.indexOf(",") + 1, 
    border1.lastIndexOf(",")
    ); 
     var B= border1.substring(
    border1.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, 
    border1.lastIndexOf(")")
    );

 hex = "#"+rgbToHex(R,G,B);
 document.getElementById("textToColor").innerHTML=text1;
document.getElementById("textToColor").style.color=hex;

}

document.getElementById("B1").onclick=getColor1;
document.getElementById("B2").onclick=getColor1;
document.getElementById("B3").onclick=getColor1;
document.getElementById("B4").onclick=getColor1;



function exitFrom(){
   /*if (document.getElementById("openColor").style.display=="block"){
     var pattern = /(?:^|\s)buttonA(?:\s|$)/
     if (document.activeElement.className.match(pattern)){}else{
      alert("Color for text was not picked. You will have to do it from begining");
          document.getElementById("openColor").style.display= "none";
     }
   }*/
}
window.addEventListener("click", exitFrom);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying a listener or a function callback for the *addEventListener* method, an *event* argument is provided. You can then act against that event, to check for its target element. Something like this:

```
function exitFrom(event) {
    if (e.target.contains(document.getElementById("openColorHref")) || document.getElementById("openColor").contains(e.target)) {
        return
    }
    // rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: My understanding of JS is still not at level to get to solution here. So I must  ask If you could help more.

Comment: @Sailo1 It will be great if you could explain exactly what you expect. It is unclear what should happen when a click is made.

Comment: Test the fiddle when  code in function exitFrom(){ is not commented. The alert message will come out to soon. And change the first line of code from "openColor" to"colorPalete1".

Comment: I need alert when colorPalete1 is diplayed, if user clicks in window and not on color button. Alert can be:   alert("Color for text was not picked. You will have to do it from begining");

Comment: But when I comment the code out, after clicking the "To peint the text", I get the alert: "Color for text was not picked. You will have to do it from beginning". It doesn't make sense, and it make it harder to understand what's going on.

Comment: This is when code is not working as it should. The alert has to come out only when #colorPicker1 is displayed and user click somewhere else on the window and not on the color button. maybe I should tell now to ignore the code which is commented.

Comment: I made another fiddle to illustrate what i want. https://jsfiddle.net/pr2501/n0bcxwuf/13/

Comment: Here is the solution  for the problem ilustrated in previouse  fiddle in :https://jsfiddle.net/pr2501/n0bcxwuf/64/